# View custom org agendas without first storing in org-agenda-custom-commands?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

What is the preferred method of building (viewing) a custom agenda without modifying `org-agenda-custom-commands`?  I am hoping that there is a function like `org-agenda-list` or `org-todo-list` that accepts a custom agenda command definition like those that would be added to `org-agenda-custom-commands.

Edit: **Essentially just bypassing the org-agenda dispatcher / stored custom commands**

An example taken from the org-mode manual:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("O" "Office block agenda"
     ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 1)))
      (tags-todo "+PRIORITY=\"A\"")
      (tags-todo "computer|office|phone")
      (tags "project+CATEGORY=\"elephants\"")
      (tags "review" ((org-agenda-files '("~/org/circuspeanuts.org"))))
      (todo "WAITING"))
     ((org-agenda-compact-blocks t)))
```

I think that org-agenda concatenates the results of individual sub-commands (like `org-tags-view`) internally.  What I'm looking to do is skip the traditional org-agenda dispatcher and construct the agenda directly from an arbitrary definition like (from the above):

```
'((agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 1)))
  (tags-todo "+PRIORITY=\"A\"")
  (tags-todo "computer|office|phone")
  (tags "project+CATEGORY=\"elephants\"")
  (tags "review" ((org-agenda-files '("~/org/circuspeanuts.org"))))
  (todo "WAITING"))
 ((org-agenda-compact-blocks t)))
```

The key being that the definition is subject only to the constraints for `org-agenda-custom-commands`.  It could simply be a `tags` agenda or a multipart one like that shown.

I originally thought that the user-defined function type that can be added to `org-agenda-custom-commands` might be the trick, but it looks like it's treated as a match predicate (it's not really mentioned in the documentation).

I'm asking because I'd like to view an agenda that has a dynamically-generated definition.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what kind of agenda you're trying to build, `org-tags-view` may do what you want:

> (org-tags-view &optional TODO-ONLY MATCH)
>
> Show all headlines for all ‘org-agenda-files’ matching a TAGS criterion.
>   The prefix arg TODO-ONLY limits the search to TODO entries.

This basically what a `tags` or `tags-todo` type entry in `org-agenda-custom-commands` does.  The rest of the custom command definition is just variable/value pairs that are `let` bound when you call `org-tags-view`.  For example,

```
(let ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Test"))
  (org-tags-view nil "+test"))
```

will find anything labeled `test` and set the title of the agenda to "Test".  Any other `org-agneda-*` variable can be set similarly.